# Having trouble setting up neo4j.rb for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j, neo4j.rb

I am trying to use neo4j.rb on rails.
Following https://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/v9.4.0/Setup.html this site, I tried

```
rails new myapp -m http://neo4jrb.io/neo4j/neo4j.rb -O
```

this shows an error that says 
**`open_http': 404 Not Found (OpenURI::HTTPError)**
I looked it up but the page doesnt exist.
I looked at https://github.com/neo4jrb/activegraph and it says that **they changed the name from neo4j to activegraph** and I thought that that might be causing this issue. 
Can someone tell me which url I should use to set up neo4j.rb?

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into the same issue - using

```
rails new myapp -m http://neo4jrb.io/activegraph/neo4j.rb -O
```

seems to work fine.